# copy table td only which have name class / id

Tags: javascript, html, firefox-addon

Copy table td which have customer id.

i have done copying whole table. i got this from here.

i want to copy only table td which have name class or id

I am able to copy whole table. i don't want to do it bcos it copying the table th also. i only want to copy td which have customerName id

```
<td id="customerName" class="ordervalue">Carl LoStracco</td>

 function selectElementContents(el) {
    var body = document.body, range, sel;
    if (document.createRange && window.getSelection) {
        range = document.createRange();
        sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        try {
            range.selectNodeContents(el);
            sel.addRange(range);
        } catch (e) {
            range.selectNode(el);
            sel.addRange(range);
        }
        document.execCommand("copy");

    } else if (body.createTextRange) {
        range = body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(el);
        range.select();
        range.execCommand("Copy");
    }
}
```

i use above function to copy whole table.
[look at this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k41F6.png)

i want to copy the details only Carl LoStracco / 3306 Chayote Rd NE not name or street. but with the above code it copying whole td.

Name    Carl LoStracco
Street  3306 Chayote Rd NE
City    Rio Rancho
State   NM
Country     United States
Postcode    87144-6366
Phone   5054509274
Tracking Numbers

this is what i got after copy function.

once i copy the details i want to insert into a input field but at first i want to copy the details.

i hope you get my problem, sorry for my bad english

Comment: is it possible to separate name address phone after copying whole td as i mentioned above ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query the td with the wanted id and then copy its content in a variable, then use it as a normal string:

```
var name = document.getElementById("customerName").textContent;
var street = document.getElementById("customerStreet").textContent;
```

Comment: Thanks bro it is great idea and worked. So it is possible to redirect to a page with the content i get here and insert in to that page input field ? i'm working on a firefox addon.

Comment: Yes, you could send the infos to the page trough a GET or a POST HTTP call